# How to avoid repeating chunks of code with handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have a json like this:

```
{
    "icons-container-set-1" : [
        {
          "data-tab": "tab1",
          "image" : "researchKO.png",
          "class-first" : "first",
          "fragments-title" : "Access award-winning <br> research",
          "fragments-paragraph" : "..."
        },
        {
          "data-tab": "tab2",
          "image" : "WideRangeUp.png",
          "class-first" : "",
          "fragments-title" : "A full range <br> of investments",
          "fragments-paragraph" : "..."
        }
    ],
    "icons-container-set-2" : [
        {
          "data-tab": "tab1",
          "image" : "im.png",
          "class-first" : "first",
          "fragments-title" : "...",
          "fragments-paragraph" : "..."
        },
        {
          "data-tab": "tab2",
          "image" : "img.png",
          "class-first" : "",
          "fragments-title" : "...",
          "fragments-paragraph" : "..."
        }
    ]
}
```

This is for a set of tabs componentes. The html looks like this:

For the set 1 and 2 the only thing I am changing is on the first line of code `{{#each process.icons-container-set-1}}` for `{{#each process.icons-container-set-2}}`:

```
{{#each process.icons-container-set-1}}
    <div class="icons-container {{{class-first}}}" data-tab="{{{data-tab}}}">
        <div class="icon-up">
            <img src="assets/images/{{{image}}}" alt="">
        </div>
        <p class="fragments-title">{{{fragments-title}}}</p>
        <p class="fragments-paragraph">{{{fragments-paragraph}}}</p>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Any suggestions in order to avoid repeating that chunk of code in the html?

I did a separate component with the above html but I realised that I have to be repeating the same, and actually I don't have only 2 sets of tabs, there are like 6.

I think if there is an option to get the index of the sets in the json file:

Like: `{{#each process.icons-container-set-*@GET_INDEX_HERE*}}`

Suggestions?

Comment: How about convert this json obj to a array, then use '#each'?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add something to your json try to do so and then you'll be able to iterate over your element. For example you may name your list of icon-container-sets :

```
{
   "icon-container":[
      {
         "icons-container-set":[
            {
               "data-tab":"tab1",
               "image":"researchKO.png",
               "class-first":"first",
               "fragments-title":"Access award-winning <br> research",
               "fragments-paragraph":"..."
            },
            {
               "data-tab":"tab2",
               "image":"WideRangeUp.png",
               "class-first":"",
               "fragments-title":"A full range <br> of investments",
               "fragments-paragraph":"..."
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "icons-container-set":[
            {
               "data-tab":"tab1",
               "image":"im.png",
               "class-first":"first",
               "fragments-title":"...",
               "fragments-paragraph":"..."
            },
            {
               "data-tab":"tab2",
               "image":"img.png",
               "class-first":"",
               "fragments-title":"...",
               "fragments-paragraph":"..."
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and then

```
{{#each process.icons-container}}
  {{#each icons-container-set}}
        <div class="icons-container {{{class-first}}}" data-tab="{{{data-tab}}}">
            <div class="icon-up">
                <img src="assets/images/{{{image}}}" alt="">
            </div>
            <p class="fragments-title">{{{fragments-title}}}</p>
            <p class="fragments-paragraph">{{{fragments-paragraph}}}</p>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```